# How to use my MS account to sync settings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to sync my VS Code settings via my MS account. So in VS Code I click on to the "Accounts" button in the lower-right corner, then I selecte the "Turn on settings sync ..." option, then I leave all options selected in the popup and click on to the "Sign in & Turn on" button, then I select "Sign in with Microsoft", which opens a new browser window/tab at location

```
localhost:65508/signin?nonce=51WxyZA16ATjV7nsMVFlrg==
```

However, that keeps on loading forever, nothing happens.
Is this an issue on my end, how can I select my MS account for VS Code sync?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: @PranayDeep In my case this was an issue due to using VS Code on Windows on a WSL Linux project. However, in the meantime this has been fixed by MS and thus now solved my issue.